# Operations that use only CPU

Tags: xcode, swift

Can you please tell me some example code where we use ignorable amount of RAM and storage but heavy use of CPU? Like, if I run a loop and perform some division operations with float, this is supposed to use CPU but not RAM or storage. I mean tell me some CPU expensive operations.
Will you consider it a good example:

```
for _ in 0 ... 999999 {
    0.5 + 67.3 / 78.1003 / 34.87
}
```

Comment: An infinite empty loop. Lots of CPU, zero memory. Why?

Comment: take your time `(1 ..< 10000000000000).reduce(0) { $0 + $1 / 100 }` (my Xcode is using 300% CPU and fan going crazy with it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code above will keep the CPU plenty busy because you are performing repetitive, quick operations. The CPU does work whenever it has to perform any sort of operation. It also does not take very much RAM, so you nailed your code example! :)